# What does Gitlab Host URL means in configuring gitlab in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

The one specified in [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) in the Configuring the Jenkins server section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief: **it's Yours GitLab API Endpoint without `api/v4`**. If you want to use Webhooks, or [GitLab OAuth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitLab+OAuth+Plugin) it very important field.

Comment: where can i find that? im not using a hosted gitlab. i am using gitlab.com

Comment: It's simple `https://gitlab.com/`. If You want to check how it's work login into yours account. Next type in you browser `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/<YOUR_USER_ID>`

Answer (score 1):

if you use gitlab as global type https://gitlab.com/. but if you have other domain that use with gitlab, should use https://gitlab.your-domain-name.com. it work fine for me, just add https://gitlab.com because my project store on gitlab.com as simple. :D