# gitlab & jenkins, "no client-builder found that supports server" error

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have created and set a Gitlab tokne, and try to set `Gitlab host URL`:
like this:

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/1*****3`

`1*****3` is my gitlab ID. I test the `api` on browser is work, get a `json` document.

ref: [What does Gitlab Host URL means in configuring gitlab in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382771/what-does-gitlab-host-url-means-in-configuring-gitlab-in-jenkins)

But when I chick `test connection`, is show the error message, like this:

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: no client-builder found that supports server at https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/1*****3
    at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient.autodetectOrDie(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:310)
    at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient.delegate(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:298)
    at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient.access$200(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:14)......`