# Client error: HTTP 302 Found, Jenkins connect to Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, server, gitlab

[image]

I can't connect Jenkins to my Gitlab. I get the following error message:

> Client error: HTTP 302 Found

I have created a token in my Gitlab and put them in credentials. I dont know why happen it. I have my service Jenkins running in port 8080 and I setup my server for reverse proxy.

```
    ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
    ProxyRequests     Off
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443""

    # Local reverse proxy authorization override
    # Most unix distribution deny proxy by default (ie /etc/apache2/mods-en$
    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
```

I need help, to solve the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The GitLAb Host URL, when [configuring the Jenkins server](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#configure-the-jenkins-server) should be https://gitlab.com only.

As mentioned in "[What does Gitlab Host URL means in configuring gitlab in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51382991/6309)", it represents the GitLab API Endpoint, *without* `api/v4`.